# Does this notion appear outside recursion theory?

Tags: logic, category-theory, computability, universal-algebra

Suppose we have a set $X$ and a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of *partial* functions from $X$ to $X$. Say that $A\subseteq X$ is **$\mathcal{F}$-stable** if for every $f\in\mathcal{F}$ with $dom(f)\supseteq A$ we have:

- there is some $g\in\mathcal{F}$ with $dom(g)=f[A]$, and
- there is some $h\in\mathcal{F}$ with $dom(h)=X\setminus f[A]$.

*(Here "$j[C]$" is the set $\{j(c): c\in C\}$.)*

My question is:

> Does this notion appear anywhere?

---

... Outside recursion theory, that is.

This notion is an abstraction of the intuition behind "generalized finiteness" in [higher recursion theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631#toc), where we often take the stance that the most important feature of finite sets in classical recursion theory is that **a set is finite iff its image under a recursive function is always recursive**. This heuristic, for example, led to the key insight that "hyperarithmetic" is the analogue of *finite*, not *recursive* (which led to [metarecursion theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08715106)). In some contexts it's a bit more complicated than that (e.g. in [$\beta$-recursion theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484381900152)), but the basic idea is definitely an important one.

So the starting point is the situation when $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of partial recursive functions $X\rightarrow X$ in some generalized recursion theory; "domain of a partial computable function" is then the standard analogue of "recursively enumerable," and the recursive sets in this theory are those which are both r.e. and co-r.e. Dropping all assumptions on what a "generalized recursion theory" should consist of, we get the notion above, which is applicable to any family of partial functions; I'm curious whether it shows up anywhere. *(Obviously what I'd love is for it to crop up somewhere far from recursion theory where we can then subsequently interpret the situation as a kind of generalized recursion theory.)*

At a guess, the two most plausible candidates to me are category theory and universal algebra (hence those tags). But I'm happy for examples coming from anywhere. Indeed, the further away from logic, the better.

Comment: I don't know projective geometry, just a little bit I've heard of that. But I strongly feel this notion can appear in this type of geometry, because if one looks at point sets like $G$ as the objects, then morphisms will be partial maps between the point sets, say $ G$, $G'$. Namely a partial map $ f: G \rightarrow G'$, maps $ f : 
 A\rightarrow G' $,whose domain $ f := A$ is a subset of $G$. And what is $A$ intuitively? $A$ is a part of the shape that remains constant under the projection map, and that is meaningful in the above definition that it is used "stable" terminologically.

Comment: Though I don't see any examples, I feel that another aspect of the situation may be relevant, namely existential quantification. The way you use functions in $\mathcal f$, both to produce $f[A]$ and to refer to the domains of $g$ and $h$, all involve existential quantification over $X$. That's fine for recursion, since $\Sigma^0_1$ is closed under $\exists$ over $\omega$. And it's fine for metarecursion since $\Pi^1_1$ is closed under $\exists$ not only over $\omega$ but also over Kleene's $\mathcal O$ and $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$. But [continued in next comment]

Comment: the fact that $\Pi^1_1$ isn't closed under $\exists$ over $\mathbb R$ seems to make $\Delta^1_1$ subsets of $\mathbb R$ less like finite sets and more like recursive sets (e.g., recursive in Kleene's ${}^2E$). So I suspect that it would be good to look especially for examples with suitable $\exists$-closure.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's definitely true, but I worry about the balancing act a bit. At present I'd be happy for examples of just the above phenomenon given that I don't know a single (non-contrived) example at present. Once some of those exist - if they do - I'd then want to concentrate further on those with additional nice properties.